# Singleton w/ HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, singleton

I am a university beginner in Java and I have a little question about exercise below, please, could someone help me about this?

I need to make an application using a Singleton and instantiate one HashMap in a memory that have information at file.xml, like this:

```
<propriedades>
<configuracao>
 <chave>timeoutApplication</chave>
<valor>10</valor>
</configuracao>
</propriedade>
```

This is my code by now:

```
public class ArquivoLog {

   private FileWriter arquivo;
   private static ArquivoLog log;

   private ArquivoLog(){
      try {
          this.arquivo = new FileWriter("C:\\arquivo.xml");
      }catch (IOException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(ArquivoLog.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }        
   }

   public static ArquivoLog getInstance(){
      if(log==null){
         log = new ArquivoLog();
      }
      return log;
   }
}
```

I don't know how to implement HashMap in this case.

Comment: You could add a new private field like `private Map memory = new HashMap();` just between the fields `arquivo` and `log`.

Comment: @TobiasOtto I wouldn't recommend using raw collections. For this purpose, a `Map<String, Object>` is likely a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for share guys. I was trying to using `HashMap<String, Integer>` but not successful yet. Can I use this HashMap with FileWriter to make a xml file?

Comment: Are you expected to create a file as part of this singleton OR read that XML file and keep it in the HashMap to be accessed by any component in the application?

Comment: @YogendraJ, I need read XML file at "C:\file.xml"  and keep in the HashMap. Sorry if I was not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the link between XML and hashmap so I am assuming here that you need to parse the XML and populate hashmap values. In this case you can use JAXB to read from xml and save it to hashmap.

If there is no parsing involved then you can simply declare and use HashMap as follows

```
private FileWriter arquivo;
private HashMap map;
private static ArquivoLog log;
```

One suggestion:

Implement double check locking mechanism in your singleton.

```
 if(log==null) {
     synchronized (ArquivoLog.class) {
         if(log==null) {
            log = new ArquivoLog();
         }
     }
 }
```

Populate the hashmap values when you create the instance and expose the hashmap using public method. Also based on your logic update the xml file if the hashmap values are changed (if its allowed as per your business logic)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this and looking about JAXB.

Comment: To keep things simple you can also use DOM parser. Here is the sample code: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: Thank you again. I don't knew about DOM. I'll check this out and try to implement.